# jquery click handler not closing slide in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Relevant JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7u2fy/

I was trying to have a slide in menu that slides in on a button click and slides out when you press escape or click anywhere outside the menu. I also wanted to darken the non-menu portion of the screen when the menu is active.

My problem is the jquery click handler isn't working for the closing of the menu.

The jsfiddle looks a little weird for even though in my actual project it looks fine and only the jquery click handler isn't working.

The specific code that's not working...

```
$('#site-wrapper.show-nav #site-canvas').click(function () {
    toggleNav();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler is working fine, the issue is the grey block that appears on this element: #site-wrapper.show-nav #site-canvas:after

It essentially blocks any clicks, remove the below property 'absolute' and your can click.

```
#site-wrapper.show-nav #site-canvas:after {
  *position: absolute;*
}
```

The issue is within your CSS not your JS, please see this fiddle of clicking working: http://jsfiddle.net/7u2fy/1/

Comment: wouldn't that remove the dark overlay though? EDIT: the click handler was still not working even after removing absolute

Comment: it will yes, I was highlighting that the click is working. which browser are you using? have you tried using keyboard and tabbing to element and hitting enter? that also allows the hide to work...

try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7u2fy/1/